# Rails : State_machine won't update state

Tags: ruby-on-rails, state-machine

I use the gem state_machine (most of you must know it!)
At the beginning it works perfectly, but since a while, the state won't update while the transition send me true :

here is the state machine configuration :

```
state_machine :state, initial: :draft do
    after_transition on: :validate, do: :create_order
    event :init do
      transition nil => :draft
    end

    event :validate do
      transition :draft => :validated
    end

    event :publish do
      transition [:draft, :hidden, :validated] => :published
    end

    event :hide do
      transition [:published, :validated] => :hidden
    end
  end
```

when I do :

> > Car.last.publish
> >     The answer is "TRUE"
> >     but the state won't update !

What th matter ?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You mean, updated state is not saved?

Comment: scuse my poor english.

when I publish the Car, the state stay at "draft" in database instead of "published"